# I dont know how im supposed to initialize a variable when it is a const

Tags: pointers, constants

```
const CRecvProxyData *pData;

float flYaw = pData->m_Value.m_Float;   

float simTime_since_lby_update = ent->GetSimulationTime() - time_at_update[index];
```

I get an uninitialized local variable 'pData' error please help

Comment: Maybe `const CRecvProxyData *pData = new CRecvProxyData;` Although then you want a value in the next line. I think to answer the question we need a [mcve]

Comment: Without additional information this question is not really answerable. We know less on how to correctly initialize `pData` than you do. Since we don't have enough context.